# Comparison of r^2 (square of Pearson's r)

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I have the correlation coefficient(square of Pearson's r) between two signals X and Y measured from different locations say M1,M2,M3 and M4 on the body.The experiment is done on 4 subjects.
The values are tabulated as below. The highest correlation for each subject is highlighted in red.

I wanted to know if I can make comparisons based on these values both vertically and horizontally and draw the following conclusions:

1.M4, M1, M2 and M2 are the best measurement location for Subjects 1,2 3 and 4 respectively. (intra-subject comparison)
2. As M3 gives the highest mean correlation of 0.7875 for 4 subjects, it can be considered as best location for measurement (inter-subject comparison)

[image]

Comment: I would try to pool together all Subjects' data and calculate correlations against M3.

Comment: The R^2 is itself a statistic, with confidence intervals that can be calculated. If you want to make comparisons based on this, you probably want to consider those intervals too.